# UserDefaults Error in Mac Catalyst App, Recommended solution doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, mac-catalyst

I am getting the following error when my App runs as a Mac Catalyst app, it does not happen on iOS.

```
2020-05-25 11:33:40.249195-0400 Wasted Time[80637:885413] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
    ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled
) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x600002c01b00> (Domain: com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
```

I have confirmed that my my App Sandbox setting ahas "User Selected File" Permissions set to "Read/Write", and have cleaned build build folder and derived data before rebuilding the app.

I am running Xcode 11.5 (11E608c) and am developing on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5 Beta(19F94a)

I am also seeing this on Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) and macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4

So it does not appear to be an issue with the version of Xcode of Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing with multiple people, this appears to be a Xcode problem, and the code doesn't actually have any issues.  Closing this post